# "国籍" refers to nationality or the country of citizenship?

Tags: translation, meaning

As I pointed in the title. What is the correct answer to 国籍. Is it, for example, Japanese or Japan. I am confused because I found contradictory translations when I tried to look on the internet. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question, but does this question mean, in English, you have to reply differently depending on whether the question was "What's your nationality?" or "What's your country of citizenship?" For now I'm not seeing a meaningful difference...

Comment: @naruto sorry for not being clear on this point. This is actually an application form where l have the choice to fill it wether in Japanese or in English. I am filling it in English so I get confused what is the correct answer country vs nationality.

Comment: Um, for example, does one has to write *French* when asked their 'nationality' and *France* when asked their 'country of citizenship' on an application form written in English? Anyway something like 日本です is the usual answer for 国籍は何ですか, although adding 人 doesn't do harm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

国籍 means "country", so we say 日本国籍, not 日本人国籍. To have 日本国籍 means "to be Japanese".

Answer (score 2):

国籍 means nationality and it implies that the one who has the 国籍 has a formal document for it. (籍 originally means "document" e.g. 戸籍)

I think a translation like "the country of citizenship" is used  in a sentence like 国籍は日本です

Answer (score 0):

According to 国籍法 *Japanese Nationality Act*, 国籍 refers to Japanese Nationality.

Here is 国籍法 *Japanese Nationality Act*.
http://www.moj.go.jp/MINJI/kokusekiho.html

> （この法律の目的）
>   (Purpose of This Act)
>    　　　第一条　日本国民たる要件は、この法律の定めるところによる。
>   Article 1　The requirements of Japanese citizenship shall be governed by the provisions of this Act.

**English translation of Japanese Nationality Act**
http://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/law/detail/?ft=1&re=01&dn=1&co=01&ky=%E5%9B%BD%E7%B1%8D%E6%B3%95&page=1